# Can you create an object which acts like None when typed into the interpreter in Python?

Tags: python, nonetype, repr

Is it possible to create a class that has the following behavior?

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x
>>>
```

I tried the following

```
class X:
    def __repr__(self):
        return ""
```

which results in

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x

>>>
```

and also the following:

```
class X:
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(None)

>>> x = X()
>>> x
None
>>>
```

and other ideas like returning `None` from `__repr__` errors when you call `repr` on it, and deriving from `NoneType` just errors.

Comment: Why do you want this behavior?  Trying to determine if this is an XY problem...

Comment: I want to have a function return a value that can be tested, but doesn't show up if you use it as just an expression at top level in a shell

Comment: But why? Why would you go out of your way to make your object harder to inspect? Someone who gets `x` as the result of an expression wants to see what `x` is.

Comment: For the same reason that `None` doesn't show up, the idea is that 99% of the time, you won't want the value, but the remainder of the time, you might...

Comment: Pretty sure that this is special cased at the level of the repl...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make a value that behaves as you want, but you can change how the interactive prompt displays values.  See [sys.displayhook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) for how to customize the display.